# Pointer addresses are getting overwritten

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

using namespace std;
int d;
long long int *arr = (long long int*)malloc(d * sizeof(long long int));
    
int* func(){
    int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p =5;
    return p;
}

int main(){
    int *p = NULL;
    p = func();
    d =10;
    printf("add of p: %d\n\n",p);
    
    int i=0;
    for(;i<10;i++){
        printf("Add of arr: %d \n",arr+i);
    }
    
    
    return 0;   
}
```

The address assigned to pointer 'p' is getting overwritten by the address of some location of array 'arr'.
Why is this happening? even when 'malloc' assigns memory in heap.

Also if I use the same data type for both 'p' and 'arr' then no such problem occurs.

Code Output:

[image]

Comment: `printf("add of p: %d\n\n",p);` you invoke *Undefined Behavior* attempting to print a pointer address with `"%d"` -- all bets are off. Same in your next `printf`. You print a pointer address with `"%p"` and the pointer must be cast to `(void*)`.

Comment: There is definitely undefined behavior in play here since `d` is being used without initialization

Comment: It can only be C++.

Comment: The code is totally written in C. Not even iostream is included and it was tagged in both C and C++.

Comment: @WARhead `d` is global, it is initialized to `0` by default.

Comment: @JohnBollinger -- scratching head -- why can it only be C++? (not saying your wrong -- just blew by me...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin what happens if `malloc` is called with 0 as argument? I haven't really worked with `malloc`

Comment: @WARhead - let me check C standard -- I think it is UB, but I'll confirm. [C11 Standard - 7.22.3 Memory management functions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3) -- *Implementation Defined Behavior*

Comment: @RohanBari, it uses a `using` statement, and it has a function call at file scope.  These are C++-only features, with the latter, at least, relevant to the question.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin C doesnt have namespace, i think so it can only be C++

Comment: But you can remove the `using namespace std;` and it is pure C. -- I guess if the OP is using a C++ compiler (like `g++` instead of `gcc` it could be C++)

Comment: @JohnBollinger I agree with your statement. But you can clearly see, the way of using Boolean, memory allocation are used in C program. Removing the namespace use will make it pure C.

Comment: The `using namespace std;` is the only thing in that code which makes the code unambiguously C++.    The `malloc()` call outside a function is an extension supported by some compilers.  All the other code that produces output is valid as C or C++.   And gives undefined behaviour in both C and C++ due to using `%d` (repeatedly) to print a pointer.   Pointer addresses are not being overwritten.   They are simply being output inappropriately.

Comment: @Peter C wouldn't allow a `malloc` call when initialising `arr` either.

Comment: Your code might not even compile without warnings.... If you use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as your compiler, be sure to enable all warnings and debug info, so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` for C code, or `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` for C++ code. Then use your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)....). Be aware of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR)

Comment: That's what I was looking for (missing). The allocation of the global -- I agree john.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin & co., removing the `using` statement **does not** make it valid C.  Again, it has a function call at file scope, in the initializer for `arr`.  This is not allowed in C, but it is integral to this question.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  - Actually the malloc call (which is passed a value of zero) has nothing to do with the question - it is a red herring.   The only thing done with `arr` is to add a integral value to it, and pass the result to `printf()`.   The allocated memory is never modified or read.      The behaviour is undefined due to mismatch of format specifier and argument passed.     If `arr` was initialised as a null pointer, or as the address of a variable, or even as the first element of an array with 10 or more elements, the behaviour would be equally undefined.

Comment: @Peter, the `malloc` call is integral because the OP supposes that space for 10 `long long int` is in fact allocated, so they conclude that the computed value of `p` is a pointer into the interior of that space.  Yes, the OP is mistaken about the amount of space allocated, and yes, they do not attempt to access the space, but there would be no question in the first place without the `malloc`.

Comment: Almost certainly, fixing the UB by changing to a `%p` directive would leave the behavior, and hence the question, substantially unchanged.

Comment: the code is in cpp, but thanku you so much i found the solution.

Comment: You're using C headers, C memory allocation, and C I/O. Literally the only thing that makes your code C++ is the `using namespace std`. Proper C++ code for the same thing would be very different. If you're going to write C, don't use C++ stuff. If you're going to write C++, use the C++ features such as vectors instead of manually managing memory.

Comment: cpp contains all these features as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You clearly think that you've allocated an array of size 10. However when this expression is executed

```
long long int *arr = (long long int*)malloc(d * sizeof(long long int));
```

`d` has a value of zero. `d` is a global variable so by default is initialised to zero. Confusingly there is also another variable called `d` in `main` but this has no bearing at all on the allocation of `arr`.

Comment: that's a type which i now corrected, there is no local d. But the problem was as u mention that 'd' has a value zero. So thanks for ur response

Answer (score 1):

You use `d`'s value to decide what to pass to `malloc` before you set `d` equal to ten. Then when you do set `d`'s value to ten, it's a different `d` because you have one at global scope and one scoped inside of `main`.

Comment: Worse, it's a different `d` that is set to 10.

Comment: even then, that `d` is local variable and not the global one, since it is redefined

Answer (score 0):

This is just the `Undefined Behaviour`. There are some memory-related issues (like accessing an array out of the bounds..) where C/C++ just say what should happen if everything is correctly accessed and every other thing is left undefined. So it may work someday or it may not.

Exactly as the above answers mentioned, there is an ambiguity from your side which lead to undefined behaviour.